# AngularJs bracket after "return"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

Why doesn't the angular directive work when bracket follow under return?

```
app.directive("alert", function () {
  return 
  {
     restrict: "EA",
      template: "<div>Alert!!</div>"
  };
});
```

But does work when the bracket is adjacent to the return:

```
app.directive("alert", function () {
  return {
     restrict: "EA",
      template: "<div>Alert!!</div>"
  };
});
```

Comment: And I just learned something new about JavaScript.  https://jsfiddle.net/o4ctxght/  Nice question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you just have return that considered to be return nothing `undefined`(nothing). You must return something on same line otherwise its same as that of `return;`

& when you have it on same line it considered as you returned object(`DDO`) from directive.

Answer (score 1):

That's because JavaScript will take `return` as a single operation, this because `return` by itself is a valid operation.

First example would be the same thing as having

```
app.directive("alert", function () {
  return;
  {
     restrict: "EA",
      template: "<div>Alert!!</div>"
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of automatic comma insertion in javascript.

When you move the bracket to the next like, the compiler presumtiuously inserts a semi colon at the end of your line, thinking you've forgotten it.

```
app.directive("alert", function () {
  return ;
  {
     restrict: "EA",
      template: "<div>Alert!!</div>"
  };
});
```